# How to run aws glue jobs on incremental data at s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services

On first day i kept my data as Folder 1 in s3 and run the job from glue,
 i got the expected output.
On second day i kept my data as Folder 2 in same parent folder and run the job from glue,
folder1 data got replicated and output for data in folder 2 also came.

How can i avoid replication of data from folder1?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the bookmark in your AWS Glue Job? Enabling the bookmark will cause Glue to keep track of what it has already loaded. If you ever have to reload all your data, there's a "reset bookmark" option on the Jobs menu.